# How do I change a box components direction in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, direction, hbox

With mx:Box I can set the direction to be either "horizontal" or "vertical". I'd like to reverse the order of the components in the box though. For example:

before:

|button1| |button2| |button3|

after:

|button3| |button2| |button1|

I've created a custom component that lives in a mx:Box and would like to do this in as simplest a way as possible.

Any help appreciated,

Many thanks,

Bryn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest that comes to mind is to override the addChild method in Box:

```
import mx.containers.Box;

public class ReverseBox extends Box
{
  public override function addChild(child:flash.display.DisplayObject):flash.display.DisplayObject
  {
    return addChildAt(child, 0);
  }
}
```

hth

Koen